# Single Sign on with Saml

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to integrate SSO through SAML request in our ASP.NET Application. I am using KentorAuthService Library to achieve this. will using kentor library be a solution for authenticating from other identity providers like(one login, rapid identity etc) or should I do implement specifically based on the identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the IDP.

If the IDP supports the SAML 2.0 protocol, you can use Kentor.